# Generate FxCop Results xml in teamcity

Tags: xml, teamcity, fxcop

I need to set up a build step in Teamcity for FxCop. I also need to generate the fxcop results in a xml file. Please help me. I am new to Teamcity. I would really appreciate if someone could post screenshots also.
I did google, but could not able to understand properly.

Comment: Hi all, I could able to generate the FxCop-results.xml to the checkout directory in Teamcity. I could finally able to get the .xml file from FxCop Build step. Now, I am struggling to generate .xsl file . I would like to get the .xsl file to the same checkout directory. To get the .xml file, I did not set up any step in teamcity. By default, the I got .xml file to the checkout directory. Please help, I stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get FxCop running in TeamCity, would need to follow these steps:

1. Install FxCop on the Agent (or all of agents if you have more).

   Download it here: https://fxcopinstaller.codeplex.com/
2. Edit file `buildAgent.properties` and add information about FxCop instalation folder.

   Add line: system.FxCopRoot=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0
3. Create the build step. It is easy now. The interesting settings are:

   Runnert Type: FxCop

   FxCop version: 10.0

   Assembiles: for example bin*.dll

   Report XSLT file: %system.FxCopRoot%/Xml/FxCopReport.xsl

   Additional FxCopCmd options: for example `/ruleSet:"=%teamcity.build.workingDir%\Core\ProjectRules.ruleset"`. 
   I use this to specify custom rules settings

The XML is then generated to a path which can then be found in the build log. To change the path you can use more FxCopCmd parameters, more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429449%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Let me know if you have any questions.